# Placing rectangles inside a circle properly

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement a canvas image that will contain a circle and a number of rectangles inside the circle. The circle will be generated according to the given diameter (user input) and the rectangles will be generated according to the given height and width (user inputs). The number of rectangles will be created according to the formula shown below.

Rectangles per Circle = d * pi * ((d / 4 * S) - (1 / sqrt(2 * S))) d – Circle Diameter S – Rectangle Size

For a 300px diameter circle, and 10px width with a 10px height rectangle, there will be 641 rectangles inside the circle.

But I need to place the rectangles properly inside the circle something like below.

[image]

Comment: rectangles ? not squares ?

Comment: I'm quit sure if you would shift certain rows slightly to the right, you could fit in another box at the left side. Apparently you have some rules which you didn't list. More importantly, what have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Can you share your attempt and pinpoint the problem with it?

Comment: you have to start your calculations from the center, it's a double central symmetry; 
and use pythagoras to determine if your squares are outside the circle

Comment: You give function  `d * pi * ((d / 4 * S) - (1 / sqrt(2 * S)))` and example d = 300 and S = 10 which gives `300 * PI * ((300 / 4 * 10) - (1 / sqrt(2 * 10))) = 706647.602616` well short of `641`. At best I can only fit 588 boxes

Answer (score 1):

You function `d * pi * ((d / 4 * S) - (1 / sqrt(2 * S)))` does not work.

Below is an example that fits boxes `SQUARE_SIZE` to a circle `CIRCLE_RADIUS` via the function `drawBoxesInCircle` and outputs to the console the number of boxes drawn.

```js
const CIRCLE_RADIUS = 150;
const SQUARE_SIZE = 10;


// cx cy are circle center
// rad is circle radius
// size is box size
function drawBoxesInCircle(cx, cy, rad, size) {
  var boxes = 0;
  var y = 0;
  for (y = 0; y < rad; y++) {
    const boxCount = ((rad * rad - (y + size) ** 2) ** 0.5) / size | 0;
    let i = 0;
    while (i < boxCount) {
       drawBox(cx + i * size,       cy + y,        size);
       drawBox(cx - (1 + i) * size, cy + y,        size);
       drawBox(cx + i * size,       cy - y - size, size);
       drawBox(cx - (1 + i) * size, cy - y - size, size);
       boxes += 4;
       i++;
    }
    y += size;
  }
  console.log("Box count = " + boxes);
}

const TAU = Math.PI * 2;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2 + 2;
canvas.height = CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2 + 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffdcc8";

function strokeCircle(x, y, r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r + 0.5, 0, TAU);
  ctx.stroke();
}
function drawBox(x, y, size) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, size, size);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

strokeCircle(CIRCLE_RADIUS + 1, CIRCLE_RADIUS + 1, CIRCLE_RADIUS);
drawBoxesInCircle(CIRCLE_RADIUS + 1, CIRCLE_RADIUS + 1, CIRCLE_RADIUS, SQUARE_SIZE);
```

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```